# Making a numpy array with mixed types and writing it as csv

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to create a numpy array to hold different types like this:

```
na_csv_output = np.zeros((len(ldt_timestamps),1),dtype=('i4,i4,i4,a10,a10,i4'))
```

The problem with this is that all 6 values are stored as a single entry, whereas I would prefer it to be 6 columns so that they can be written properly as a CSV. Is there any way this can be done by using a numpy array? (or some other type like list)

P.S.

Even when I try to write the values that I get from the initial try to a file using

```
np.savetxt('eventResults.csv', na_csv_output, delimiter=",")
```

it says

```
TypeError: float argument required, not numpy.string_
```

so that's another problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access each column, use  `na_csv_output['f0']` or `f1` `f2`, etc, where `f` stands for field.

To save it to a file, first make it a 1D array,

```
na_csv_output = np.zeros((len(ldt_timestamps)),dtype=('i4,i4,i4,a10,a10,i4'))
```

To save it, you can go for something like this for example

```
np.savetxt('eventResults.csv', na_csv_output, fmt='%f, %f, %f, string= %s %s, last number = %f', delimiter=",")
```

Comment: That's exactly what I need, but it's not working correctly, if I try to make it 1D and insert elements like na_csv_output[0] = [(1,1,1,'a','b',1)] it says TypeError: expected a readable buffer object, and if I make it na_csv_output = np.zeros((len(ldt_timestamps),1),dtype=('i4,i4,i4,a10,a10,i4')) it says AttributeError: fmt has wrong number of % formats.  %f, %f, %f, %s, %s, %f

Comment: Use instead `na_csv_output[0]=(1,1,1,'a','b',1)` for an assignment, and stick with a 1D array.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/). It makes csv operations really easy.

```
import pandas as pd
# omit second argument to np.zeros to get 1-d data
na_csv_output = np.zeros((len(ldt_timestamps),),dtype=('i4,i4,i4,a10,a10,i4'))
df = pd.DataFrame(na_csv_output)
df.to_csv('eventResults.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('eventResults.csv','w') as f:
    for x in xx:
        np.savetxt(f,x,fmt='%f, %f, %f, %r, %r, %f')
        # np.savetxt(f,x,fmt='%r',delimiter=', ')
```